# Solve the equation $e\log_4 \left(\sqrt 7^{2^x}\right) = 3^{4x}$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, graphing-functions, problem-solving

Can anyone help me to solve this equation:
$$e\log_4 \left(\sqrt 7^{2^x}\right) = 3^{4x}$$
I tried to solve it graphically using [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/?lang=en) to get the intersection point with the $x$-axis $(y=0)$ and I got $x = 0.13885$ but I cannot prove this algebraically.

[image]

Comment: What does $\log_4 (\sqrt 7)^{2^x}$ mean?  Does it mean $((\log_4 \sqrt 7)^2)^x$ or $(\log \sqrt 7)^{2^x}$ or $(\log (\sqrt 7^2))^x$ or ... what....

Comment: it means $\log_4 (\sqrt {7})^{2^x}$

Comment: That is still ambiguous. Is it $(\log_4(\sqrt 7))^{2^x}$ or $\log_4(\sqrt{7}^{2^x})$? In any case, the (numerical) solutions computed by Mathematica (-0.076 and -0.095, respectively)  do not match your solution of 0.13855.

Comment: $\log_4(\sqrt{7}^{2^x})$

Comment: @GoranMalic I believe it is commonly assumed that a^b^c=a^(b^c).  Since $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$, someone would just multiply if that's what they meant.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Ok, but the issue was whether $2^x$ belonged to the argument of the log, or if it was log to the power of $2^x$. Since $\log x^a$ is commonly assumed to mean log of $x^a$, but that variation didn't correspond to the numerical solution that Mario obtained with Geogebra, I asked for additional clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rewrite it
$$2^xe\log_4 \sqrt{7} = 81^x \Leftrightarrow e\log_4 \sqrt{7} = \left(\frac{81}{2}\right)^x$$

Now, take, for example, the natural logarithm:

$$x = \frac{\ln e+\ln \left(\frac{\ln\sqrt{7}}{\ln 4} \right)}{\ln 81 - \ln 2}= \frac{1+\ln\ln\sqrt{7}-\ln \ln 4}{\ln 81 - \ln 2}$$

Picture added after comment:

[image]

Comment: your answer is correct but I forgot the letter "e" before the log, I will edit it

Comment: @Mario : Thanks for letting me know. :-)

Comment: you are welcome ; can you resolve the equation again?

Comment: @Mario : I extended the solution a bit

Comment: Did you see the graph? I uploaded the pic
your answer is close to the correct one

Comment: I double checked it with WA: It is the solution. Your solution corresponds to $e \left( \log_4{\sqrt{7}}\right)^{2^x} = 3^{4x}$.

Comment: You only need to shift some parentheses in the expression on the LHS in your graphing tool to get the correct result.

Comment: can you check this picture https://ibb.co/JKL3tM7

Comment: can you draw it please? https://www.geogebra.org/graphing?lang=en

Comment: Just give me a few seconds. Your second picture belongs to $\left(e  \log_4{\sqrt{7}}\right)^{2^x} = 3^{4x}$ and not to $e \left( \log_4{\sqrt{7}}\right)^{2^x} = 3^{4x}$.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can you draw it

Comment: @Mario : I have added it to the answer.

Comment: I hope this clears up all doubts. I am off now for some hours. Gonna check in later. See you. :-)

Comment: OK! Can you explain why my graph was incorrect?

Comment: Just see the different equations I posted in my comments. Geogebra has certain rules to interpret mathematical expressions. To make sure that the expression is correctly interpreted, it is often necessary to put in parentheses (brackets). Otherwise, as in your case, an expression might be interpreted differently from what you expect. Exactly this happens here.

Comment: Thank you very much